# Trying to decode an event using rescript-json-combinators

Tags: rescript, bs-json

Trying to create an equivalent for decodeEvent using rescript-json-combinators. I couldn't figure out how to replace "Decoder(decoder)" since Decoders have been made abstract in rescript-json-combinators. Trying to use Decode.decode didn't work.
Any idea on how this could be solved?

```
   let decodeEvent = (Decoder(decoder), value: Web_node.event) =>
    try decoder(Obj.magic(value)) catch {
    | ParseFail(e) => Error(e)
    | _ => Error("Unknown JSON parsing error")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `decodeEvent` seems to be two-fold:

1. To convert a `Web_node.event` to `Json.t` in order to use Json decoders on it.
2. To return a `result` instead of raising an exception on error.

The `rescript-json-combinators` API already has a `result`-based API. That's part of the reason why the implementation is now hidden and requires the use of `Json.decode` to run the decoders. That seems to be all that's missing here:

```
let decodeEvent = (decoder, value: Web_node.event) =>
  value->Obj.magic->Json.decode(decoder)
```

Comment: Trying to do the same thing to this function
`let succeed = v => Decoder(_value => Ok(v))`
for some reason if I use the expression bellow where the decode function is defined it works, if I try to use it in a different file it says that the expression inside decode should not be a function.
`let succeed = v => Json.decode(_value => Ok(v))`
Any idea on why this is happening and is there a better equivalent for this function ? Thank you

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be a function, but a decoder. `Json.decode` is used to _run_ a decoder. `succeed` should _be_ a decoder. Or rather a function that returns a decoder. This is where you need to use `Decode.custom`. Something like `let succeed = v => Decode.custom((. _json) => v)` should work, I think.